# clojure look inside a function

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

Functions are easy to create:

```
(defn x [y] (* y y))
(x 8) ;64
```

But they are hard to inspect becuase

```
(print x) ; #<core$x my-namespace$x@34990a46>
```

is not a very useful. Is there a way to peer inside?

If there is no way, a complex program maybe a gigantic macro maybe could track where functions are being created and composed, like valgrind tracking lengths of arrays, etc. Perhaps some tool has been written that does this debugging.

Edit: 
**This is a partial duplicate of another question, the difference being programmatically vs at the REPL. However, I don't know how different these tasks are, as the answer is complicated.**

Comment: This question is different from the linked question because it is asking about programmatic examination rather than getting the definition. That question predates the general adoption of the `source` function and should be taken only in it's historical context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is, in it's pure form, not possible. Functions are largely opaque to the code that calls them. Which has lead many Clojure programmers to prefer passing data when possible (maps specifically) which can be composed more easily.

It is possible to grab the source to the function and make some inferences from that though it's hard because the source may have included some state from the system at the point of compilation that no longer exists, amongst many other challenges.

core.async is a huge macro heavy library that would really benefit from this ability, though it lacks the ability to resolve async actions across function calls because it's presently considered to be impractical to do this correctly in a general sense. There may be cases where you can get some of the effect you look for by examining the source though.